Who is this goddess?
Who is this goddess? My father bought it in India, decades ago.


Looks like Parwathi to me. Maybe from Tamila Nadu.

It is not necessary that it is an idol of some Goddess ..  sculptors build statues of even Apasras also. In this case it is not clear which Goddess is it.

Thank you for your comments they are appreciated!

Does she have two different sets of earrings?
